# Array and object in java

Tags: java

I have problem in array and object..
like consider this:

```
dog[] mydog = new  dog[1];

mydog[0]= new dog();

mydog.name= "Bart!";
```

this line create an object in heap with reference mydog.

and `mydog[0].name = "Bart!";` .

is it. okey

but
    mydog[0].owner= "jay"  ;

my question is we created one object in heap. and  already. store the dog name in it . than how we can store  one more name "jay" in. it...

pls explained with example

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan I gotta ask why you pointed that guy out

Comment: I think I understood your problem.. Look to my answer and tell me if you understand what I mean.

Comment: yaa  but I am getting output both name.

Comment: So what's the problem in having two String pointers in a single object?

Comment: I can't understand pls explain where these value store and in which these value store

Comment: ok I might have missunderstood. I posted a diagram, it should be clearer now.

Comment: is it more clear now?

Answer (score 3):

You created an array of dogs, with one dog in it. However, the dog array doesn't store the properties, it stores the dogs. And each dog stores the properties you assign it i.e. name and owner

Comment: you mean which. object I created.  I can store tow value of same class  class

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand that second sentence.

Comment: I mean I can store two
value(dog name and owner) in same object which I created in heap

Comment: I don't know what a heap has to do with it, but you can store as many variables you want in a single object (up to a point), as long as they're defined.

Comment: You haven't shown your dog class, so this is kind of difficult to explain.

Answer (score 2):

Actually

```
mydog.name ...
```

Will not work.

What you need to do is

```
mydog[0].name=...
mydog[0].owner=...
```

That allows you reference individual elements in the array.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely the structure of your MyDog class.

```
public class MyDog{
public String owner; // should be private
public String name;  // should be private 
}
```

Now, each MyDog object is composed of (contains) 2 String Objects (owner and String). So, the 2 String Objects are part of every MyDog insance.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I probably missunderstood your question before.
I made a diagram of what the stack and heap should look like. Hope you can read it (maybe download and zoom ;) ) and helps in understanding.
In your stack you've got a pointer (mydog) to an array of dog objects. The array object is in the heap and it stores pointers (here just one as the length is 1) to the dog object, I also show the index of the array above the array box and the array's length variable.

I am assuming your dog class looks something like the following:

```
public class dog{
    public String owner;
    public String name;
}
```

[image]

Tip: class names usually start with uppercase.

---

Old answer, can help you with some hints anyway.

```
mydog[0].name = "jay!";
```

Your dog instance in the heap has got a pointer to a String object, always in the heap of course.
With the above line you are:

1. creating a new String object that says "Bart"
2. changing the 'name' pointer to point to this new string instead of the new one.

So, you don't store *one more name "jay" in*, rather you are replacing the old "Bart" object with the new "jay" one (from the dog object prospective).

Be careful anyway in understanding that you are only modifying the pointer in the dog object.
This means that if you had another pointer somewhere else, pointing to that "bart" string, that, would not change. Conversely if no other pointer points to the old "Bart" string, then "Bart" will be eventually collected and deleted by the garbage collector.